# Play a sound with Jquery when a result founded in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid which draw a table. I have the column return and inside (besides more data) I have a span like this

```
   <span class="return" id="ret0>4.25%</span>
```

So I have in my webpage a lot of spans

```
  <span class="return" id="ret0>4.25%</span>
  <span class="return" id="ret1>4.15%</span>
  <span class="return" id="ret2>5.35%</span>
  <span class="return" id="ret3>7.85%</span>
```

How could I check them all, in the gridComplete event ,and play a sound when I find a return higher than 6%?

I prefer a way without checking the Id if possible.

Maybe is easy but I am still learnign Jquery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.return').each(function(){

    if(parseFloat($(this).html()) > 6){
    // value is great that 6, do stuff
    }
});
```

Also you need to have closing quotes around your ids

```
<span class="return" id="ret0>4.25%</span>
```

should be

```
<span class="return" id="ret0">4.25%</span>
```

Comment: thank you! yes I have the quote, I inserted bad in my question. I am going to try!

Comment: how can I break the each when I find one?

Comment: After you do your logic, you can add `return false;`.  This would stop the loop after the first instance it finds a value greater than 6.